# How do I get to my Keynote 6.5 themes folder?

Tags: macos, keynote, iwork

I've created a theme using `File > Save Theme` and would now like to share it with others. Where in the world is it though? It's visible in the `File > Change Theme` area but I can't find the source folder.

Googling gives me reference to `/Library/Application Support/Keynote/Themes` or `~/Library/Application Support/iWork/Keynote/Themes/`, both of which aren't right for Keynote 6.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the lack of answers on Google surprising, so I had to stumble around until I found it.

Themes are located in:

`/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Keynote/Data/Library/Application Support/User Templates/`

If you're not as familiar with the command line, you can open up Terminal and simply run this to get all your themes copied to your Desktop:

```
cp /Users/$USER/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Keynote/Data/Library/Application\ Support/User\ Templates/* ~/Desktop
```

Which says "copy all contents of the current users's Theme folder to that user's desktop."